# Use boolean to check state of application objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, boolean, uialertview

I don't know is question is well-formed. So i have an uialertview shown at start application for 30 seconds. In this uialertview there is a button "ok" on which user can click and release alert. if users don't click this button for 30 seconds the alert will release. 
Here is code..

```
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome" 
                                                message:@"Welcome!" 
                                               delegate:nil 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert setDelegate:self];
[alert show];

dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC*30.0);
dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
[alert release];

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

}
```

So i have to implement the control with a boolean to check if users clicks ok or not... 
can u help me? i'm new in objective c :) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show your alert view as follows:
Assume isD is BOOL value (declare it as class member in .h file)

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome" 
                                                message:@"Welcome!" 
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert setTag:1000];
[alert show];
isD = NO;

dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC*5.0);
dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    if (!isD) {
        [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    }
});
[alert release];
```

And write the UIAlertViewDelegate method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if( alertView.tag == 1000 )
    {
        isD = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: isD = YES has a warning.. -> warning: Semantic Issue: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'BOOL *' (aka 'signed char *') from 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char')

Comment: BOOL is not pointer. How did u declare in header file? BOOL *isD; or BOOL isD; The second one is correct.